# Cannot insert or see models even though gazebo_model_path is set

Tags: ros, gazebo, sdf, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having issues inserting custom models into gazebo. Here is my file structure:

- lawnbot_ws

  - src

    - lawnbot_desription

      - models

        - grassplane

          - meshes
          - model.sdf and model.config
      - package.xml

Gazebo shows: /home/josiah/PycharmProjects/lawnbot_ws/src/lawnbot_description/models in the insert tab, however it does not show a drop down for actually inserting the grassplane model!

I also have the following line inserted in the package.xml file of the lawnbot_description package:


<gazebo_ros
gazebo_plugin_path="${prefix}/lib"
          gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/models" />

I do not understand what is wrong. I am calling:

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch extra_gazebo_args:="--verbose"
```

in the terminal and the gazebo_model_path shows:
/home/josiah/PycharmProjects/lawnbot_ws/src/lawnbot_description/models

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273777/cannot-insert-or-see-models-even-though-gazebo_model_path-is-set/) by [josiahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/32344/josiahl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem.
1st, I had a typo in the xml

HOWEVER,

More annoying was that I found that the:

/home/josiah/.gazebo/gui.ini file retained my old path name:

filenames=/home/josiah/PycharmProjects/lawnbot_ws/src/lawnbot_description/meshes

which should have been:

filenames=/home/josiah/PycharmProjects/lawnbot_ws/src/lawnbot_description/models

Why did it never update the pathname? We may never know. Very frustrating, however now I am able to insert custom models into any world I choose.

---

Originally posted by [josiahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/32344/josiahl/) with karma: 18 on 2017-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
This is really a Gazebo-specific question.

Please ask those over at `answers.gazebosim.org` in the future. You'll have a much higher chance of getting good answers there.

**Comment by [Carlos Delfino](https://answers.ros.org/users/38962/carlos-delfino/) on 2018-12-17**:
Please, you can share you package.xml and CMakeLists.txt for I learning more about this configuration?